# Mudar codificação no pd.to_datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

queria saber se há a possibilidade de mudar a codificação de um elemento retornado pela função `to_datetime` do pandas. Preciso mudar para a codificação ISO-8859-1 para comparar a data com outras que estão armazenadas num arquivo externo (TXT).

O retorno do `to_datetime` é formatado da seguinte forma: 2017-05-22 (YYYY-m-d)
O que está armazenado no arquivo TXT é da seguinte forma: 2017-22-05 (YYYY-d-m)

Obs 1.: estou carregando os arquivos do TXT através da função `read_csv` do pandas.

Obs 2.: precisei definir a codificação `ISO-8859-1` na hora de carregar os arquivos com o read_csv, pois estava dando erro com a codificação padrão (utf-8, acredito).

formatação da data inserida pelo usuário:

Obs.: tentei usar o parâmetro format, mas não surtiu efeito.

```
lastDate = pd.to_datetime("2017-05-22")
```

leitura dos arquivos do TXT:

```
readingTXT = pd.read_csv(self.fileFolder+file,delimiter="\t",usecols=[0,1,21],encoding="ISO-8859-1",tupleize_cols=True)
```

Comment: Ja tentou comparar: `data1.isoformat()==data2.isoformat()`? ou converter as duas datas em tuplas e comparar os elementos? O idela seria q vc colocasse mais alguma coisa na pergunta, parte do arquivo, por exemplo ou como o usuario faz a inclusao.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver essa questão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> O `.to_datetime` do pandas parece aceitar datas em diversos formatos, então acredito que você poderia ler tanto a data do seu TXT quanto qualquer outra, e compará-las depois disso:

```
import pandas as pd

minha_data = "2017-22-05" # data no formato do TXT
data_panda = "2017-05-22" # data em outro formato
data_outra = "1495411200.0" # unix

print(pd.to_datetime(minha_data, format='%Y-%d-%m')
  == pd.to_datetime(data_panda, format='%Y-%m-%d')
  == pd.to_datetime(data_outra,unit='s'))
```

> Resultado:
>   [image: resultado de comparação de datas]